# javascript code wrapper

Tags: 7, javascript

While using drupal 7, is it necessary for to wrap pure javascript code with jquery wrapper? (I understand that while working with jquery, I need to wrap my code inside beaviors.)

code

```
function openWin()
  {
    mycode     
  }
```

od should I wrap it like this

```
(function () {

function openWin()
  {
mycode
  }

  })();
```

Or even use behaviors? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *have* to wrap your code with a behavior or jQuery at all. That depends:

**If you want to use jQuery object with the `$` as a shorthand:**

Wrap your code like this:

```
(function($){
  //$('#something').show();
})(jQuery);
```

**If you want to execute something after an Ajax DOM change and on document ready event**

*Use behaviors.*

```
Drupal.behaviors.ysu_premium = {
  attach: function (context) {
    //jQuery('#something').show();
}}
```

*You can wrap the behavior with the above jQuery wrapper if you want to use jQuery.*

```
(function($){
  Drupal.behaviors.something_unique = {
    attach: function (context) {
      //$('#something').show();
    }}
})(jQuery);
```

When I'm working on Javascript, I always use the last snippet above.

Comment: Hi, In you examples you used jquery code right? I wanted to use javascript code. I tried to put code inside (function () {... but id did not work. So i put only plain jquery code like function openWin()
  {
    var myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
... and it works. So I am confused a little:)

Comment: The snippet in your above comment is not using jQuery, so you don't need to wrap it as shown above.